# SubString in List

Tags: java, lightweight-stream-api

I have a class and method

```
class Dictionary {
    public Dictionary(List<String> dic) {
        // ...
    }
    
    public int getCount(String substr) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What should occur:
in method **getCount** you need to use list from constructor of the class and find all strings which starts on substring **substr**

I use this solution on my interview

```
return (int) this.dic.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith(substr)).count();
```

Complexity is O(n)

Are there better solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: You could sort the list, then stop searching once you hit an item that doesn't start with your search term (only after you've found one, though). You could make a hash and group stuff by starting letters, then only look in the bucket for that letter. Either way, if this is not just for school, profile before trying to optimize.

Comment: Your solution seems fine the way you have constructed the problem. But normally, a dictionary isn't just a List<String>, it's a sorted List<String> if that's the case, then you could use a modified binary search to find the first substring that matches, and then interate from there until finding the last. After finding the last, you can return - no other entries will match

Comment: @pshemo when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because the methods are stubs... which happens **all too often**

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thanks for guidance. Removed my comment since as you claim question (in current form) doesn't fulfill CR requirements.